# Want help creating custom type inference similar to Zod

Tags: typescript, type-inference, zod, typescript-conditional-types

I am working on a library in typescript that works like ZOD, but where each object has built-in methods to persist itself in a database.

So far, I have successfully made functions that check input datatypes at runtime, but I would like to add a Zod-style type inference feature.

Unfortunately, I don't know where to start. I looked at the source code of Zod on github and found that it uses conditional types, but I still can't understand how an object instantiated at runtime (z.object) can be inferred into a compile-time type.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some sort of [mre], otherwise this question risks being closed as "needs details or clarity" or "needs debugging details".

Comment: I understand, is there a better place to ask for suggestions than SO?

Comment: _"but I still can't understand how an object instantiated at runtime (z.object) can be inferred into a compile-time type"_ In the code `z.object({ foo: z.string() })` the compiler can see the types involved just fine. But, yeah, without at least a contrived example, there's not much to answer here.